# Cannot read the values inside an Arraylist of an Arraylist returned through a soap method

Tags: java, arraylist, soap

This is the soap method

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "getCustomernamelist")
public  ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> getCustomernamelist() {
    try {
        makeConnection();
        System.out.println("Connected");
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("COnnection Failure");
    }
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> accNo = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> all = new  ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();        
    try{
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet  rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT name, acc_number FROM customer");
        while(rs.next()){
            names.add(rs.getString("name"));
            accNo.add(rs.getString("acc_number"));
        }
    all.add(names);
    all.add(accNo);
    } catch(SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("SQL Exception");
    }
    return all;
}
```

[image]

I cant access the arraylist inside the arraylist. check the image url for the image.
Thanx a lot for ur time!

Comment: You never add elements to `all`.

Comment: Thanx for the help! I changed the code still the problem is there! wish ur help

Comment: I don't see any issue here.

Comment: How do I access the inner arraylist elements? there is not get method after the outer arraylist!!! pls help :(